# VB net: Get last of colum

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have table, table format:

```
id   time_stamp
3    2013-09-05 12:00:00
5    2013-09-06 12:00:00 
12   2013-09-07 12:00:00
2    2013-09-08 12:00:00
5    2013-09-09 12:00:00
8    2013-09-10 12:00:00
```

And I want to get last of `time_stamp` column. How I do this, thank.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a `DataTable` and it's name is `table`

```
If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim lastDate As String
    lastDate = table.Rows(table.Rows.Count - 1).Item(1)
    MsgBox(lastDate)
End If
```

---

output

> 2013-09-10 12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Simple `SELECT` and `TOP` if you are using SQL SERVER

```
SEELCT TOP 1 id, time_stamp
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```